# How do I use jq to map {a:b,c:[0,1]} to [{c:c[0],a:b},{c:c[1],a:b}]?

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to trying to transform

```
{
  "login": "username",
  "emails": [
    "email_1@example.com",
    "email_2@example.com"
  ]
}
```

into

```
[
  {
    "email": "email_1@example.com",
    "login": "username"
  },
  {
    "email": "email_2@example.com",
    "login": "username"
  }
]
```

However, for the life of me I am unable to figure out how. I've looked into jq's map and reduce functionality, but I must be getting the syntax incorrect.

I would appreciate any help y'all might provide. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks to everyone that responded. As you may have guessed, this was the core problem for a larger transformation. I'm actually working on around 752 separate JSON files in a directory, each with a similar object. I wanted to transform them all into a single array of logins and e-mails. Thanks to @peak's answer, I managed to create the following:

```
jq -s '.[] | {login, email: .emails[]?}' *.json | jq -s 'map(select(true))'
```

Please note that I changed `.emails[]` to `.emails[]?` to account for the very real possibility that some values for `.emails` are `null`.

Comment: Your solution (in EDIT) seems unnecessarily complex and inefficient. Something like `jq FILTER *.json | jq -s .` should be possible, where FILTER produces a stream of objects.

Comment: HI @peak, thank you! I'm fairly new to `jq` and still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jq-esque (look, no variables!) solution:

```
[{login} + {email: .emails[]}]
```

Or even more succinctly:

```
[{login, email: .emails[]}]
```

(Maybe you could get away without the outer-square-brackets?)

Comment: Wow, this is pretty damn slick peak. Nice job! I want to give both you and @RomanPerekhrest credit for answers, but it only allows me to select one. I am going to select yours unless someone is able to tell me why Roman's is "more" correct.

Comment: Hi @peak, you're able to drop the outer square brackets, but doing so would require the new object to be thrown into a map call in order to place it into a new array. Your brackets are more succinct and work well.

Answer (score 2):

**`jq`** approach:

```
jq '.login as $uname | .emails | map({email: ., login: $uname})' input.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "email": "email_1@example.com",
    "login": "username"
  },
  {
    "email": "email_2@example.com",
    "login": "username"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, use map function over the email list.

```js
data = {
  "login": "username",
  "emails": [
    "email_1@example.com",
    "email_2@example.com"
  ]
}

result = data.emails.map((x)=> ({"login": data.login, "email": x}));
console.log(result);
```

My misunderstanding, for the `jq` version look at the answer of @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: First, thank you so much for the quick response! Second, I really apologize for being an idiot, but what language/framework did you use in your answer (which works, thanks!)? I am trying to accomplish this with jq, and you provided what looks like a lambda with x bound to the element of the emails array. I'm not sure how to achieve that with jq?

Comment: @akutz I didn't use any framework on the first solution. `map` function is builtin javascript which is simpler than `jq`. But I added `jq` version also. It virtually pretty much the same with slight different in syntax.